# The Time To First Byte Still High

Tags: server, webserver, hosting, server-response

I tested my website in webpagetest.org and there are the result :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zXJp.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQR67.png

I tried google it and finding a a way to solve the time to first byte problem but still it's showing poor result.The solution that i have tried:

1)Checking on the server.
2)compression
3)Minify JS and CSS
4)optimizing images
5)use CDN

Can anyone give me another solution that can help on reducing the TTFB?Thanks in advance.